# How to deploy SwiftUI macOS app directly on you mac?

Tags: xcode, macos

When working with SwiftUI iOS App, I can deploy or generate the app on my iPhone easily by running the app project with my plugged device.

However, when working with macOS app, I notice that no matter how many time I run the project, the app is not generated or deployed on my mac.

How can I generate or install the macOS app directly on my mac?

Comment: Need more info on this question. What are your target settings? Build setting? What destination are you trying to run it on? What error (if any) are you seeing?

Comment: Are you just building or archiving the app? In the first case drag&drop it from the build folder (menu Product > Show Build Folder) into /Applications, in the second export it to /Applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`How can I generate or install the macOS app directly on my mac?`.

In Xcode, go to the `Product` menu, then Archive -> Distribute App -> Copy App -> Export As: MyApp

Go to the selected folder and your app is there, double click on it.

Comment: I followed your steps, and it worked amazinly